# Parse.com which should I choose between ParseFacebookUtilsV4 and ParseFacebookUtils.framework

Tags: xcode, facebook, parse-platform

Parse says here: https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-facebook-users

to import:

```
#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>
```

but few lines above, says to import ParseFacebookUtils.framework

in docs, is said that ParseFacebookUtils.framework is for iOS only.

I tried, can't get the right import.

Comment: I am unable to understand your issue. Have you added the Parse SDK to your project? Have you included #import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h> to your file? What is the error?

Comment: My bad, there was a problem with using Stackoveflow parsing. You couldn't read all the code I wrote. Problem:  I was not able to use frameworks in order to perform login. Instructions were no consistent and could not understand with use between the two mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should import the ParseFacebookUtilsV4.framework

This is the framework compatible with the new Facebook iOS SDK / API